# Change assets paths depending on environment

Tags: java, wicket

I have a java application and I have just implemented grunt to compile my assets into a deploy folder which are all minified so I need to amend the file path so in production/live the assets are being called from the **deploy/styles/site_52.css.min** and in development environment they are being called from **assets/styles/site_52.css**, this just makes things easier to debug.

In rails I do this - `if Rails.env.production?`

#### Development Environment Path

Ultilities file

```
STYLESHEET("/assets/styles/")
```

BaseWebpage file

```
final String siteCss = "site_" + site.getId() + ".css";
add(CSSPackageResource.getHeaderContribution(StaticContent.STYLESHEET.getDir() + siteCss));
```

#### Production/Live Environment Path

Ultilities file

```
STYLESHEET("/deploy/styles/")
```

BaseWebpage file

```
final String siteCss = "site_" + site.getId() + ".min.css";
add(CSSPackageResource.getHeaderContribution(StaticContent.STYLESHEET.getDir() + siteCss));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) run Wicket in your dev environment in DEVELOPMENT mode and in production in DEPLOYMENT mode. In java you can determine the mode your running by calling:

```
Application.get().getConfigurationType()
```

which return an enum [RuntimeConfigurationType](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/RuntimeConfigurationType.html) . Then you could do it like this:

```
if (RuntimeConfigurationType.DEVELOPMENT.equals(Application.get().getConfigurationType())){
  //set dev path 
} else {
  //set prod path and extension
}
```

Also be aware the Wicket can in DEPLOYMENT mode serve compressed javascript and css resources. Take a look at [ResourceSettings](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/settings/def/ResourceSettings.html) and `setCssCompressor()` and `setJavaScriptCompressor()`. I would recommend trying this approach.